# window is not defined in afterEach (Global After Hooks) - VueJs Router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vue-ssr

I am getting error as `window` is not defined in `afterEach` route hooks.

```
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  console.log(window);
  // need to track ga event here.
});
```

I think `afterEach` route hooks execute on server-side render-time, so `window` is undefined here. please correct me if i am doing wrong here. if i am not wrong, then is there any router hooks which only execute on client side?

Comment: routing happens completely on the client since its javascript thats handling the routing. So you get `window` available in every hook. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wtpuevc6/188/

Comment: @Vamsi i am getting error in node console that window is not defined :(
i am using vue-ssr in my application.

Comment: In node there is no `window` object...its `global` in nodejs

Comment: i mean to say, in vue server-side-rendering  afterEach hooks execute on server-render time, that's why window undefined issue is throwing in node console.